# Compare two lists of First and Last Names to find matches

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, linux

I currently have two tables in SQL Server: TableA with 40,000 records and TableB with 2.1 million records.
Each table has 3 columns: RowID, First_Name, and Last_Name.

I am currently taking the First and Last name from the first row of TableA and comparing it to the First and Last name in EVERY row in TableB until it finds a match.  However, as you might imagine, my computer does not have enough/strong enough resources to complete this task.  It will run for a few hours then SQL Server will crash, and it doesn't save any of the work it has already completed.  I have thought about only allowing the loop to run for a set number of records and then restarting the loop from there so I can preserve some data before SQL crashes, but that's going to take forever.

I am looking for suggestions for other programs or languages to solve this problem.  I'm going to keep trying to perfect my SQL query in the meantime to speed up this process, such as by only comparing records if they have the same initials.  I don't really know much about other programs or languages, so I'm open to trying something other than SQL Server.  I don't know if there's a language out there that is better with resources or better with "timing out" than SQL Server is.  I know a lot about Linux, so if there's something out there that I can utilize Linux to save on some of the resources compared to Windows 8, I would definitely be open to that.  I don't know if something like Python would work better, a Linux version of SQL, etc?

I appreciate your help and thank you for your time!

EDIT -----  Here's a simple version of the Query I'm running.

```
DECLARE TableANameF     ,TableANameL
    ,TableBNameF        ,TableBNameL
    ,TableARowIndex     ,TableBRowIndex
    ,TableARowCount     ,TableBRowCount
    ,NameFDifference    ,NameLDifference

SET TableARowIndex = 1

SELECT TableARowCount = COUNT(RowID)
FROM TableA

WHILE (TableARowIndex <= TableARowCount)
    SELECT TableANameF = FIRST_Name
        ,TableANameL = LAST_Name
    FROM TableA
    WHERE RowID = TableARowIndex

    SET TableBRowIndex = 1

    SELECT TableBRowCount = COUNT(RowID)
    FROM TableB

    WHILE (TableBRowIndex <= TableBRowCount)
        SELECT TableBNameF = FIRST_Name
            ,TableBNameL = LAST_Name
        FROM TableB
        WHERE RowID = TableBRowIndex

        SET NameFDifference = DIFFERENCE(TableANameF, TableBNameF)
        SET NameLDifference = DIFFERENCE(TableANameL, TableBNameL)

        IF (NameFDifference > 3 AND NameLDifference > 3)
            --INSERT INTO ANOTHER TABLE TO TRACK MY MATCHES
      --INCREMENT TableBRowIndex
  --END TABLE B WHILE LOOP
 --INCREMENT TableARowIndex
END
```

Comment: Where is your database now, `sql server`? why is a tag `excel`?

Comment: Looks like you forgot include index on your table. That query should be easy.

Answer (score 2):

If you create index for `first_name` and `last_name` on both tables this should be really fast.

```
SELECT A.*
FROM  TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B
        ON DIFFERENCE(TableANameF, TableBNameF) > 3
       AND DIFFERENCE(TableANameL, TableBNameL) > 3
```

The problem here is `DIFFERENCE` wont use any index.

The other solution is create one store procedure to run the query you made and saving the index in another table so you can resume it if query fail.

Comment: I do have an index on both First and Last name for both tables.

I don't want to simply INNER JOIN because I want to be able to use the DIFFERENCE function to see if the names are similar.  I am dealing with records that came off paper so there's room for error on the side of the person who typed the information into the table off the paper.

Comment: And you query is similar to this one? And are single index or composite index as Gordon show?

Comment: Well that is a very important information you forgot include. Maybe you should add some working query?

Comment: After reading your update. I made some changes. Let me know if that help?

Answer (score 2):

I think you merely need indexes:

```
create index idx_tablea_firstname_lastname on tablea(firstname, lastname);
create index idx_tableb_firstname_lastname on tableb(firstname, lastname);
```

I'm not sure what exactly you want to get, but you should be doing a query in the database as opposed to looping:

```
select a.*, b.rowid
from tablea a join
     tableb b
     on a.firstname = b.firstname and a.lastname = b.lastname;
```

SQL is the correct language/tool for this problem.  You just have to allow the database to do the work.

Comment: OP update question, maybe you want take a second look. Im out for today.